# Renaming sidebar menu dynamically with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

am working on project which needs to generate sidebar menu dynamically.

```
<div class="sidebar-menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="header-menu">
        <span>General</span>
      </li>
      <?php                 
            foreach ($Business_Types as $key => $business) 
            { ?>

      <li class="">
        <a href="#">
          <span id="<?php echo $business->business_id ?>"><?php echo $business->business_name; ?></span>
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">New</span>
        </a>
            <?php } ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

this is the jquery code:

```
$('#menu_id or class_name ').click(function(){
    var obj = $('menu_id').val();
    if(obj != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Vendors_search/check_obj_availability",
            method:"POST",
            data:{obj:obj},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp.status == "success")
                $('#search_x_result').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + resp.message + '</div>');

                else    
                $('#search_x_result').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + resp.message + '</div>');

            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

so, anyone can help me to give id or class to each menu fetched using jquery.

Comment: what's the issue what do you see on the outputted html?

Comment: Actually, i want to get an indivudual name or id of each menu, so that i can use it to fetch its data from database

Comment: I get that but what do you get at the moment when you view source of the page? what is the id?

Comment: am getting their id values from database. but the issue is on how can i use these values in jquery or ajax to fetch other information from database depending on those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give the id a name then follow by an id. like below

```
<span id="menuitem_<?php echo $business->business_id ?>"><?php echo $business->business_name; ?></span>
```

If you have 5 items they will out but like :

```
<span id="menuitem_1">Test Business</span>
<span id="menuitem_2">Test Business2</span>
<span id="menuitem_3">Test Business3</span>
<span id="menuitem_4">Test Business4</span>
<span id="menuitem_5">Test Business5</span>
```

Then use ajax and jquery to get the clicked menu item id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('[id^="menuitem_"]').on('click',function(){

    var menuID = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; // this will give you the id of the clicked item


    //continue with ajax to fetch data for the item


});
</script>
```

Comment: ok let me try this.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. @DidosRukundo

Comment: It works Brother! thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sidebar-menu').attr('id', 'value');
```

You could replace 'value' with a dynamically created / fetched value of your choice in javascript